# Passing around context.Context in Golang

Tags: go

I am currently "gracefully" handling HTTP server `net/http` shutdown which works perfectly fine (*I am not asking you to review server shutdown*). As seen in the code below the `context` is created **first time** directly in server package when I run the application. What I've done afterwards is (*this is the one I would like you to review please*), I've created a `context.Background()` **before** calling the server and pass it to server. Is this acceptable/feasible practise in Golang?

*Why I want to create a `context` beforehand while everything is already working fine?*

- It is because I need a few key-value pair in `context` so that I can use them throughout the application.

**CURRENT IMPLEMENTATION WITH CONTEXT IN SERVER**

**cmd/auth/main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/BentCoder/auth/internal/http"
)

func main() {
    srv := http.NewServer(":8011", 10)
    srv.Start()
}
```

**internal/http/server.go**

```golang
package http

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

type Server struct {
    http    *http.Server
    timeout int64
}

func NewServer(adr string, tim int64) Server {
    return Server{
        http: &http.Server{
            Addr: adr,
        },
        timeout: tim,
    }
}

func (srv *Server) Start() {
    log.Infof("starting HTTP server")

    idle := make(chan struct{})

    go shutdown(srv.http, idle, srv.timeout)

    if err := srv.http.ListenAndServe(); err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Fatalf("failed to start/close HTTP server [%v]", err)
    }

    <-idle

    log.Info("shutdown HTTP server")
}

func shutdown(srv *http.Server, idle chan<- struct{}, tim int64) {
    sig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    signal.Notify(sig, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGHUP)

    <-sig

    log.Infof("shutting down HTTP server in '%d' sec", tim)

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(tim)*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    if err := srv.Shutdown(ctx); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to shutdown HTTP server [%v]", err)
    }

    close(idle)
}
```

**output**

```bsh
INFO[0000] starting HTTP server                          source="server.go:42"
^C
INFO[0004] shutting down HTTP server in '10' sec         source="server.go:82"
INFO[0004] shutdown HTTP server                          source="server.go:54"
```

**THIS IS WHAT I DECIDED TO DO**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/BentCoder/auth/internal/http"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.WithValue(context.Background(), "SomeKey", "SomeVal")

    srv := http.NewServer(":8011", 10)
    srv.Start(ctx)
}
```

And update server package (the relevant bit) as seen below.

```golang
func shutdown(ctx context.Context, .....
    ...
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Duration(tim)*time.Second)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've actually improved the design, because now unit tests can inject their own context and thus the `shutdown()` becomes testable. Pure gold.

But your stated reasons make me wary. I'd pass a parameter (e.g. struct) to `Start()` or `NewServer()`  There aren't many good uses of `WithValue` that make your code more readable and neater.

Also docs for WithValue warn that "The provided `key` must be comparable and should not be of type `string` or any other built-in type to avoid collisions between packages using context." So that's a big problem with your example.